# API Яндекс.Карт в приложении вконтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api, yandex-maps-api

хочу подключить карту из конструктора карт в приложение вконтакте, как я понимаю, нужно прописать этот код в "первый запрос к API"?
`https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=<ключ>`?

Но приложение с картой не работает: Сайт yandex.ru не позволяет установить соединение.

1. Какой вид ключа нужно получить в кабинете разработчика?
2. Какой код нужно прописать в "первый запрос к API"?

Comment: Для карт Конструктора не нужно получать ключ или подключать JS API, т.к. Конструктор сам генерит вам готовый код виджета с картой. Насчет интеграции ВКонтакте непонятно, что значит "первый запрос к API", может, там вообще нет механизма для интеграции таких виджетов.

Comment: Другими словами хочу создать приложение вконтакте, которое будет показывать мою созданную карту из конструктора карт яндекса.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте страничку со своей картой, а при создании приложения в ВК, зарегистрируйте его как Iframe приложение. В настройках приложения есть пункт Адрес IFrame, туда размещаете ссылку на свою страничку и указываете размер этого ифрейма.
И учитывайте, что приложения Вконтакте будут работать только по протоколу https:// 
т.е. придется потратится на сертификат.

В самом же приложении "Запрос к API"  это запрос к API Вконтакте, а не карт.
У меня, например, он выглядит следующим образом:

```
method=getProfiles&uids={viewer_id}&format=json&v=2.0
```

подробнее про методы можно прочитать в документации:  https://vk.com/dev/api_requests